# Enabling edit access to fields en mass

Tags: administration, security

Is there a quick and easy way of enabling edit access to all or a selection of fields for an object for a particular profile?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it from the profile. From the [help](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_fls.htm&language=en_US)

1. From Setup, click Manage Users, then click Permission Sets or Profiles.
2. Select a permission set or profile.
3. Depending on which interface you're using, do one of the following:

   - Permission sets or enhanced profile user interface—In the Find Settings... box, enter the name of the object you want and select it from the list. Click Edit, then scroll to the Field Permissions section.
   - Original profile user interface—In the Field-Level Security section, click View next to the object you want to modify, and then click Edit.
4. Specify the field's access level.
5. Click Save.

Comment: This is a manual process and if we have multiple objects/orgs to configure can be tedious. Is there an easier way to do this?